# React Native functional component, how to run a function from inside the component

Tags: react-native

I have a Login component.  One piece of the component is a password field that you can toggle the security on.

```
       <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <TextInput
                    style={Theme.formField}
                    onChangeText={text => textInputChange('password', text)}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={AuthStyles.pwIcon} onPress={togglePasswordView}>
                    {data.secureTextEntry ?
                        <Feather size={20} name="eye" size={24} color="#CDE3E2" />
                    : 
                        <Feather size={20} name="eye-off" size={24} color="#CDE3E2" />
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

pressing the touchable opacity calls:

```
    const togglePasswordView = () => {
    console.log('toggle pw view');
    setData({
        ...data,
        secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry
    });
}
```

The whole component looks like:

```
export const Login = ({navigation}) => {
   // some code
  const togglePasswordView = () => {
    console.log('toggle pw view');
    setData({
        ...data,
        secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry
    });
}


return (
  // ... 
  <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <TextInput
                    style={Theme.formField}
                    onChangeText={text => textInputChange('password', text)}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={AuthStyles.pwIcon} onPress={togglePasswordView}>
                    {data.secureTextEntry ?
                        <Feather size={20} name="eye" size={24} color="#CDE3E2" />
                    : 
                        <Feather size={20} name="eye-off" size={24} color="#CDE3E2" />
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
  // ...

 )
```

My issue is that pressing the icon doesn't console log or run the function.  How can I make this run?

Comment: I've tried the exact same dynamic of code, and worked well. Did you tried reset and clean the cache ?

Comment: Thanks of the tip. That did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the arrow function:

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={AuthStyles.pwIcon} onPress={()=>togglePasswordView()}>
```